# How to load images from mipmap folder programmatically?

Tags: android, mipmaps

How to load images from the `mipmap` folder programmatically (as done with the drawables)?

```
  img.setImageResource(imageId);
```

I am using Android Studio 1.2.1.

Comment: Can't you just use the id like normal? `getDrawable(R.mipmap.your_drawable);`

Comment: And the code in your question seems wrong...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800708/how-to-load-images-from-mipmap-folder-programatically/30800780#30800780

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, he was asking how to reuse the launcher icon, not how to set it as the default launcher.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In **Android Studio** We have **mipmap** instead of drawable
You Can Find Documents Related To Your Assets [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)

You can use it Like

```
 img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do

```
img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.imageid);
```