# Where is the image folder for drawable in the Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in Android and I am following a tutorial on the Web. In the tutorial these folders are existing in their project structure:

```
res
    drawable-hdpi
    drawable-ldpi
    drawable-mdpi
```

While in my project has only these folders:

```
res
    drawable
```

And I also tried changing the Android to Project View but still same structure. The only difference are in the Project View I can see some folders that are hidden in the Android View like these:

```
mipmap-hdpi
mipmap-mdpi
mipmap-xdpi
mipmap-xxdpi
mipmap-xxxdpi
```

Can I just copy my images into the drawable folder like this?

```
drawable
    - image1.jpg
    - image2.jpg
```

Or do I need to create a folder for `hdpi, ldpi and mdpi`?

Thats all guys. When I try to use Eclipse those folders are existing in the project structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29294557/1527458

Comment: I try top copy-paste my images in the drawable but there's no option for selecting which folder should I put my images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800708/how-to-load-images-from-mipmap-folder-programatically/30800780#30800780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While in my project has only these folders:

You can make your own folder when its not yet created. just follow the naming convention.

> And I also tried changing the Android to Project View but still same
>   structure. The only difference are in the Project View I can see some
>   folders that are hidden in the Android View like these:

Just leave as it is. Nevermind the hidden files/folders.

> Can I just copy my images into the drawable folder like this?

It depends on your application. If you want to support different screen densities then you should follow the android resource folder. Refer to this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

> Or do I need to create a folder for hdpi, ldpi and mdpi?

Yes you can create it. Remember just follow the naming convention of folders.

Comment: Is it safe to create those folders?

Comment: Thanks for a very clear explanation about my issue. :-)

Answer (score 1):

the main reason folders are named as hdpi, ldpi and mdpi is for the application to be able to select the most appropriate size of the image on the device its running unless you want the image to be the same across all devices the just drop it in the drawable folder else you will have to make the appropriate sizes and put them in their respective folders