# I dont have a drawable folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't seem to have a drawable folder in Android Studio to add images..

Can I create one and will it work OK??

I'm new to this so simple steps would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In the top left of android studio, above the file tree. There should be a thing that says `Android` and an android guy. Click that and set it to `project`. Do you see the folders now? Under `app/src/main/res`.

Comment: No its not there, there is the layout and mipmap folder but no drawable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the image folder for drawable in the Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309533/where-is-the-image-folder-for-drawable-in-the-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Just go to your res folder and create a folder called "drawable" yourself - it will work just fine. Note that you might have to add resource-qualifiers (like `-xhdpi`), e.g. for pngs.

Answer (score 2):

in res folder right click then click "show in explorer" and then create new folder as "drawable"
come back to android studio, you will get drawable folder under res directory.

Answer (score 1):

Set the file structure to `project` then under `app/src/main/res` you can simply create a `drawable` folder. Just right click the `res` folder and create a new directory. Name it `drawable`.